# has_many and belongs_to how to reference the relationship both ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, relational-database

I have a model invoice and a model invoice_layout.

```
invoice
  belongs_to invoice_layout
end
```

(the invoice table has a invoice_layout_id)

```
invoice_layout
  has_many invoices
end
```

Can I just reference `invoice_layout.invoice` or does it work in both directions so that i can call `invoice.invoice_layout` ?
If that is not possible, how can i achieve that?

best regards
denym_

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Are you asking if you could do with only one of `#belongs_to` and `#has_many`, without having to declare both on class level in model ?

Comment: No just if it work both ways, because every example I found in the interweb showed only the has_many to belongs_to referential.

Comment: Ok, so selected answer is indeed correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these associations, you have methods `Invoice#invoice_layout` and `InvoiceLayout#invoices` generated.

Answer (score 0):

yes it works both ways for example if you want to refer a invoice from a invoice_layout you'll use invoice_layout.invoices and if you want to refer to a invoice_layout from a invoice you can do invoice.invoice_layout. But for them to work properly first you need to find that particular invoice_layout or invoice from which you want to refer the other one